# How to select all entries in a table with a subquery counting entries in another table by id from the first query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: albums and photos

**albums**

| id | name | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | New Year 2022 | 2 |
| 2 | Birthday Party | 2 |
| 3 | Wedding | 2 |

For every album there are photos in photos table

**photos**

| id | album_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | IMG_0754.JPG |
| 2 | 2 | IMG_0764.JPG |
| 3 | 2 | IMG_0654.JPG |
| 4 | 3 | IMG_1254.JPG |
| 5 | 3 | IMG_0054.JPG |
| 6 | 3 | IMG_0004.JPG |

I need to select all albums by user_id (in this example by user_id 2) from albums table, and count all photos from photos table, so that I get something like

| id | name | user_id | photo_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | New Year 2022 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | Birthday Party | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | Wedding | 2 | 3 |

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would write it with ms-sql. You may need to tweak it for postgresql.

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.user_id, count(*) as photo_count
FROM ALBUMS a
INNER JOIN PHOTOS p on a.id = p.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.name, a.user_id
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for postgresql

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer, which is

```
select albums.id, albums.name, albums.user_id,(select count(*) from photos where photos.album_id = albums.id) as photo_count from albums where user_id = 2
```

Comment: I think this is not the best approach, it might be working but the query will not perform well on larger tables. The better approach is to use join and group by

Comment: @Sonyck thanks for the hint, I have no experience with joins and group by

Answer (score 0):

OK, after the advice of @Sonyck the solution would be

```
SELECT albums.id, albums.name, albums.user_id, count(*) as photo_count 
FROM albums 
JOIN photos ON (photos.album_id = albums.id)
WHERE user_id = 2
GROUP BY albums.id, albums.name, albums.user_id
```